# Android + jQuery - second on swipeleft wont execute

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, events, swipe

I have to do some Special things for my Webpage to work on Android the correct way. Some Images are displayed (one visible, the other unvisible) and through swipe it should be possible to Change them. No Problem so far on all OS.

But it also should be possible to zoom. Now Android starts to be Buggy. It stops the zoom-gesture because of the swipe callback. The callback itself doesn't Change the page because the view is zoomed, so there should be no break.

Now I work arround through turning my swipeleft and swiperight off while two fingers touching the Display, and tourning back on if the fingers leave the Display.

On First run I can swipe, then I can zoom with no break, but then I can't swipe anymore. The function to set the callbacks back on again is called, it set's the callbacks, but they won't be executed...

Here's the code:

```
app.utils.scroll = (function(){
var $viewport     = undefined;
var swipeDisabled = false;

var init = function(){
    $viewport = $('#viewport');

    $viewport.mousewheel(mayChangePage);

    // On touchstart with two fingers, remove the swipe listeners.
    $viewport.on('touchstart', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.touches.length > 1) {
            removeSwipe();
            swipeDisabled = true;
        }
    });

    // On touchend, re-define the swipe listeners, if they where removed through two-finger-gesture.
    $viewport.on('touchend', function (e) {
        if (swipeDisabled === true) {
            swipeDisabled = false;
            initSwipe();
        }
    });

    initSwipe();
}
var mayChangePage = function(e){
    // If page is not zoomed, change page (next or prev).
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            app.utils.pagination.prev(e);
        } else {
            app.utils.pagination.next(e);
        }
    }

    // Stop scrolling page through mouse wheel.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
};
var next = function (e) {
    // If page is not zoomed, switch to next page.
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        app.utils.pagination.next(e);
    }
};
var prev = function (e) {
    // If page is not zoomed, switch to prev page.
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        app.utils.pagination.prev(e);
    }
};
var initSwipe = function () {
    // Listen to swipeleft / swiperight-Event to change page.
    $viewport.on('swipeleft.next', next);
    $viewport.on('swiperight.prev', prev);
};
var removeSwipe = function () {
    // Remove listen to swipeleft / swiperight-Event for changing page to prevent android-bug.
    $viewport.off('swipeleft.next');
    $viewport.off('swiperight.prev');
};

$(document).ready(init);
}());
```

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ivbVXvfH)

Any ideas what I can do to get the Events back on again?

Thanks for all Ideas.

Regards
lippoliv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it:

jQuery Mobile itself [prevents the swipe Event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js#L268) if an handler is registered, to kill an "scroll".

So I overwrote the `$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold` value and set it to 10000, to prevent jQueryMobile's preventDefault-call:

```
$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 10000;
```

Now my Code Looks like

```
app.utils.scroll = (function(){
var $viewport     = undefined;
var swipeDisabled = false;

var init = function(){
    $viewport = $('#viewport');

    $viewport.mousewheel(mayChangePage);

    // See #23.
    $.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold = 10000;

    // Listen to swipeleft / swiperight-Event to change page.
    $viewport.on('swipeleft.next', next);
    $viewport.on('swiperight.prev', prev);
}
var mayChangePage = function(e){
    // If page is not zoomed, change page (next or prev).
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        if (e.deltaY > 0) {
            app.utils.pagination.prev(e);
        } else {
            app.utils.pagination.next(e);
        }
    }

    // Stop scrolling page through mouse wheel.
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
};
var next = function (e) {
    // If page is not zoomed, switch to next page.
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        app.utils.pagination.next(e);
    }
};
var prev = function (e) {
    // If page is not zoomed, switch to prev page.
    if (app.utils.zoom.isZoomed() === false) {
        app.utils.pagination.prev(e);
    }
};

$(document).ready(init);
}());
```

Thanks to Omar- who wrote with me several minutes / hours in the jquery IRC and gave some suggestions regarding overwriting Standard values for jQueryMobile.